# Logger doesnt work with python multiprocessing

Tags: python, logging, python-multiprocessing

I am writing a test program using python multiprocessing. I am using a logger to log the progress made. However the logger doesn't seem to work. It doesn't log or print from within the child process. Cant figure out what is going wrong. Replacing logger with plain print statement doesn't help either. Below is my code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.pool import ApplyResult
import time
import os
import logging
import multiprocessing
import sys

logger=[]
class C( object ):

    def __init__(self, a, b=1):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b        


    def f(self, name):
        global logger
        time.sleep(2) 
        logger.info('****Inside f..******')
        return str(os.getpid())                


    def call_back(self, x):
        print 'Inside callback', x



    def _run(self):
        print 'Reached inside run..'
        print 'main process id ..', os.getpid()
        pool = Pool(processes=6)
        names = ['frank', 'justin', 'osi', 'thomas', 'jim', 'rock', 'stonecold', 'machoman']        
        result = pool.map_async(unwrap_self_f, zip([self]*len(names), names), 1, callback=self.call_back)
        result.wait()
        print type(result)
        print result


    def hello(self):
        print 'Running hello....'
        self._run()

def test():
    logger.info( 'Starting....test')
    c = C(1, 2)
    print 'Running test....'
    c.hello()    

def unwrap_self_f(arg, **kwarg):
    print 'inside unwrap_self_f'
    return C.f(*arg, **kwarg)    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'Loading multiprocessing...'
    logger = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr()
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)  
    test()
```

The output that I get is as below:

```
Loading multiprocessing...
[INFO/MainProcess] Starting....test
Running test....
Running hello....
Reached inside run..
main process id .. 19056
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 520
[DEBUG/MainProcess] created semlock with handle 532
<class 'multiprocessing.pool.MapResult'>
<multiprocessing.pool.MapResult object at 0x030FFB30>
[DEBUG/MainProcess] finalizing pool
[DEBUG/MainProcess] helping task handler/workers to finish
[DEBUG/MainProcess] task handler got sentinel
[DEBUG/MainProcess] removing tasks from inqueue until task handler finished
[DEBUG/MainProcess] task handler sending sentinel to result handler
[DEBUG/MainProcess] task handler sending sentinel to workers
[DEBUG/MainProcess] result handler got sentinel
[DEBUG/MainProcess] task handler exiting
[DEBUG/MainProcess] terminating workers
[DEBUG/MainProcess] ensuring that outqueue is not full
[DEBUG/MainProcess] joining task handler
[DEBUG/MainProcess] result handler exiting: len(cache)=0, thread._state=2
[DEBUG/MainProcess] joining result handler
[DEBUG/MainProcess] joining pool workers
```

It doesn't log "'****Inside f..******'" (from within function f)
Please can anybody help me figure out what I am doing wrong. Logging with multiprocessing seems to a tough nut :(
I am using Python 2.6.6. OS is windows-32bit/64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

The spawned processes won't have their logging initialised. So, you need to call `multiprocessing.log_to_stderr` in a place which will be visited by the code in each process (like `unwrap_self_f`) as well as in the main process. For example:

```
def unwrap_self_f(arg, **kwarg):
    global logger
    print 'inside unwrap_self_f'
    logger = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr()
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    return C.f(*arg, **kwarg)
```